# Why is Clion telling me that a localized version is detected?

Tags: clion

Every time I open **`Clion`**, it tells me this:

**`Localized CLion 2021.3.3 is available`**

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think CLion notify you about available [Chinese version of UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13710-chinese-simplified-language-pack----/)

Comment: But I already uninstalled that plugin. (I installed it due to an accident).